# Flutter: Why is there so much space between the children of the Column widget?

Tags: flutter, widget

My app needs to have 2 `Texts` that are to be placed one after another in the vertical direction. So I decided to use a `Column` widget. I didn't place a `SizedBox` between the 2 children of the `Column`, but they have already got quite a large amount of space in between them.

[image]

What can I do to get rid of the space? I set the `mainAxisAlignment` property of the `Column` to `center`, but that doesn't appear to be working.

```
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget> [
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/img1.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
    
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              
              children: <Widget> [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    quotationToDisplay,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Bangers",
                      fontSize: 26.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    authorToDisplay,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 23.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow
                    ),
                  ),
                )

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `Expanded` as parent of two texts inside of Column, that force to set all space posible to the widget. Remove `Expanded`.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks! But the reason I used Expanded is because the string in passed to the Text would cause a TextOverflow error. So I need the Expanded widget there. Unless there is a way around.

Comment: You can use Flexible instead

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Expanded, they are expanded equally on the main access, try not to use Expanded or add flex: 2 to the second Expanded.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a comment to the first answer by @Maikzen (which tells me the same thing as you do). Have a look.